# Flyout RegionAdapter doesn't use slide effect for the first time

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mahapps.metro, flyout

In my application I'm using `Prism` and `MahApps.metro`. I created a `RegionAdapter` for `FlyoutsControl`, this is working like a charm.

The only problem is, that when I first navigate the View into `Flyout Region,` the `Flyout` pops up instead of sliding in from the side.

I can imagine this is because it is created at runtime and added to the `FlyoutsControl` at runtime, but is there a possibility to create the `Flyout`, add it to the `FlyoutsControl` and then show it via Slide-In effect?

Just setting the `IsOpen` property to false and then to open doesn't work :(

Comment: which version of MahApps do you use? normally creating a flyout in code behind should  be working fine.

Comment: Hello Punker, thanks for you reply. Currently we are still using `0.13.1.0`. But will upgrade to the latest version soon. Nevertheless it working, but still not looking perfect. I hope you understand the problem, other wise I could make a video.

Comment: I guess there's no animation because `IsOpen` is already `true` when the flyout is added. The animation happens only when `IsOpen` is changed while shown.

Comment: That makes sens :D Is there a possibility to create or add a Flyout in closed State and open it afterwards?

Comment: I am also looking for the same subject, have you made it work? Can you please share your RegionAdapter working if possible.

Comment: No I did not find a solution for this. What I done is registering the view to the regionmanager.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing and was having issues but later i figured out the solution.

1. First, define the region name *FlyoutRegion* on `FlyoutsControl`.

   ```
   <mahApps:MetroWindow ...>
       <mahApps:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
           <mahApps:FlyoutsControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="FlyoutRegion">
               <mahApps:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                   <Style TargetType="{x:Type mahApps:Flyout}">
                       <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                       <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="{Binding IsOpen}" />
                       <Setter Property="Position" Value="{Binding Position}" />
                   </Style>
               </mahApps:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
           </mahApps:FlyoutsControl>
       </mahApps:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
   </mahApps:MetroWindow>
   ```
2. Create the RegionAdapter and register it in the Bootstrapper.

   ```
   [Export]
   public class FlyoutsControlRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<FlyoutsControl>
   {
       [ImportingConstructor]
       public FlyoutsControlRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory factory)
           : base(factory)
       {
       }

       protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, FlyoutsControl regionTarget)
       {
           region.ActiveViews.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
           {
               if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
               {
                   foreach (FrameworkElement element in e.NewItems)
                   {
                       Flyout flyout = new Flyout();
                       flyout.Content = element;
                       flyout.DataContext = element.DataContext;
                       regionTarget.Items.Add(flyout);
                   }
               }
           };
       }

       protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
       {
           return new AllActiveRegion();
       }
   }
   ```

   **Inside Bootstrapper**

   ```
   protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
   {
       var mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
       mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(FlyoutsControl), Container.GetExportedValue<FlyoutsControlRegionAdapter>());
       return mappings;
   }
   ```
3. Finally, register the desired View with *FlyoutRegion*.

   ```
   regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("FlyoutRegion", typeof(FlyoutView));
   ```

The trick here is to expose the **Header**, **IsOpen** and **Position** properties in the ViewModel and associate it with **FlyoutView**.

You can refer the detail on this [Code Project Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1042780/MahApps-Metro-Flyouts-with-Prism-Library)